# Typing out words CSS animation not working with intersection observer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got my CSS typing animation to work. It types out the words I'm trying to display. However, I tried using an intersection to trigger this animation and it doesn't work. Could somebody please help me?

```js
const observer3 = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.1) {
      entry.target.classList.add('type')
    }
  })
}, {
  threshold: [0.1]
})

const hiddenElement3 = document.querySelectorAll('.techTitle')
hiddenElement3.forEach(el => observer3.observe(el))
```

```css
.techBox {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 150, 5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgb(0, 150, 5);
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 750px;
  left: 150px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.techTitle h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 450px;
  letter-spacing: .10em;
  border-right: .15em solid rgb(0, 150, 5);
  color: rgb(0, 150, 5);
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;
  margin: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  left: 360px;
}

.type {
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes caret {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="techBox">
  <div class="techTitle">
    <h1>Website Design</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="techText"></div>
</div>
```